# SSL Certificate. For which pages?

Tags: php, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

Which pages need to use a SSL Certificate for a online shop? This site is available just for registered users and the Payment is made using a third party provider.
I suppose:  login, signup, change password.

Any other recommendation?

Comment: Why do you want to skip SSL for some of the sites? Performance?

Comment: Wow you chose the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SSL based on which pages send or receive confidential information.  Your "About Us" or "Products and Services" pages do not need to use SSL.  The pages you mentioned (login, signup, change password) do.

Comment: -1  no, you have to use ssl for every page or you will leak your session ID.  This is an OWASP a9 violation.  Please delete this misinformation.

Comment: Well, technically "About Us" and "Products and Services" do not require a session, so there is no need to send the session ID (cookies can be configured that way, so they would *not* leak). But even "About Us" might benefit from the "seal of authenticity" that SSL also provides.

Answer (score 9):

Simply make **all** pages SSL encrypted.

You probably have a session cookie and you never want it to be sent over an unencrypted connection. Besides that, there's no good reason for not using SSL on every single page.

Besides that, it looks odd if the "SSL icon" in the address bar appears and disappears on quite a few page changes.

Comment: But isn't this slow down things? Loading product images, and all the other details, without any cache and also sending all data encrypted?

Comment: Simply send aggressive caching headers. Then browsers should cache those images even if they are loaded via SSL. The encryption won't slow things down in a noticable way unless your server is really slow and the load on your site is huge.

Comment: ok, but how will handle search engines https pages?! isn't this another problem?

Comment: No. They don't really differ between HTTP and HTTPs

Answer (score 4):

It is important that you use SSL for all the pages. SSL does not only protect against eavesdropping but also ensures that the content cannot be tampered with over the wire. A man in the middle can change whatever he wants if you do not use SSL. Imagine the following scenario:

- Page A (no ssl): Pretty uninteresting
  site without secret content. Links to
  you login page (page B).
- Page B
  (ssl): Your login page.

A user requests page A. A man in the middle attack can change the link on page A so that it points at a server he controls, conducting an advanced phishing attack. Your user trusts and follows the manipulated link, because it seems to come from page A. Without SSL your user cannot tell that the server output has been tampered with. With SSL on both pages such an attack would not be possible, as long as your users care about the browser warnings (which, unfortunately, almost no one does).