# SSL: use on any page or just on login and several more forms?

Tags: performance, security, ssl-certificate

OK, I thought SSL certificate should be used on the pages that have some sensitive information displayed and on the login page, change password pages and so on.
But, on this thread [SSL Certificate. For which pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909641/ssl-certificate-for-which-pages) that was opened about 6 months ago, the best recommendation according to votes was to use ssl certificate for absolutely all pages on the web-site, even for the About page. Well... If you have a news web-site and some users have a login page and pay for advanced subscription, but you are among that users, do you read news with ssl certificate? :)

1) The first question: I've never seen a web-site with http on the About page. Can I doubt that recommendation is the best one?
2) The second question: Why doesn't Ebay follow that rules to have https connection on every page? I see they show ssl certificate only at the login page and never before you log in. After you log in, you see http, not https. What's their point? 
3) If you actually have page A for guests and page B for logged in users and page C as a "sign in page" and page "D" as registration, would you recommend to use ssl for page B,C,D, but not for A?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SSL flows both ways.  You need to worry not only about the secrets transmitted from server to client, but also about the secrets transmitted from the client to the server.  Amongst other things, the latter group includes commonly used client identification mechanisms like  basic authentication headers, authentication cookies, and session cookies for authenticated sessions.  It is possible to set things up so that such information is not transmitted from the client for certain pages, in which case it becomes safe to load them over HTTP.  However, the mechanisms for doing can be complex to maintain and require strict and ongoing auditing.  Unless you are willing to make that effort, you should be using HTTPS for all pages that an authenticated user can possibly visit.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read what was said on that link, but I wouldn't agree. SSL does have a performance hit, so using it for everything, just because you can, wouldn't make any sense. As with everything else in technology, use it sparingly.